# Foreach does not perform IF statements

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, foreach, workspace

I've implemented `foreach` in one of the multiple `for` statements of my R code. It returns the main result (the one after all the iterations), however, it does not perform an IF statement within the code.

Below the skeleton of my code (it's too long to put everything).The `if` statement does not work and variable "Disc_Time" remains the same (as initialized). What I'm doing wrong or missing? I've tried with .export="f" and .export=ls(GlovalEnv) without success.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

Disc_Time<-c("UE","Beam_order","Time")
 .... MORE VARIABLES
MDP_x<-foreach (d = 1:length(dista),.combine='c')%dopar%
{

 for (q in 1:sim)
 {  
  for (ue in 1:n)
  {      
    for (i in 1:length(seq_order_BS))
    {
      for (j in 1:length(seq_order_UE))
      {
        if(first==0)
       {
         Disc_Time<-rbind(Disc_Time,c(ue,i,D_Time))               
       }

     }
   }
 }
}
 stopcluster(cl)
```

Comment: `first` is not initialized in the code that you show.  Is it initialized in your full code?

Comment: yes, it is. The code works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To see if your if statement is working, we need to know how `first` is set, and what value it has before your loop. It does not look like `first` changes within your loop anyway, so it really should sit outside your `%dopar%` statement anyway.

That said, the if statement is not your issue. `foreach` returns a list of each return of the expression within. For example:

```
ls <- foreach(d = 1:5) %dopar% {
    return(i)
}
```

gives an list `ls` that contains the numbers one to five.

The only expression in your function is an assignment call to `Disc_Time`. This is evaluated within each of your nodes, and never returned to the parent environment. `Disc_Time` is never changed where the code was called from).

It looks as though you are trying to set a side effect of your parallel function (to change `Disc_Time`), which to my knowledge is not possible in a parallel context. Perhaps you want:

```
MDP_x<-foreach (d = 1:length(dista),.combine='c')%dopar%
{

 for (q in 1:sim)
 {  
  for (ue in 1:n)
  {      
    for (i in 1:length(seq_order_BS))
    {
      for (j in 1:length(seq_order_UE))
      {
        if(first==0)
       {
         return(rbind(Disc_Time,c(ue,i,D_Time)))
       } else {
         return(NA)
       }

     }
   }
 }
}
 stopcluster(cl)
```

`MDP_x` should then have the values you want for each `d`

Comment: So can we put the `if` statement within every `foreach...dopar` loop?